# Crystal Report Visual Studio 2010 - Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I am trying to create a crystal report to a Windows form aplication (first time), and I have the following errors when I add a Crystal Report in my Solution.

I have installed in my computer:

### SAP Crystal Reports, version for Visual Studio 2010 - Standard

### SAP Crystal Reports runtime engine for .NET Framework 4 (32-bit)

Build Errors:
Error   7   Type 'ReportClass' is not defined.  C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 22  14  TESTE
Error   8   property 'ResourceName' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a property in a base class. C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 28  31  TESTE
Error   9   property 'NewGenerator' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a property in a base class. C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 37  31  TESTE
Error   10  property 'FullResourceName' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a property in a base class. C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 46  31  TESTE
Error   11  Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' is not defined.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 57  44  TESTE
Error   12  'ReportDefinition' is not a member of 'TESTE.CrystalReport1'.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 59  20  TESTE
Error   13  Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' is not defined.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 65  44  TESTE
Error   14  'ReportDefinition' is not a member of 'TESTE.CrystalReport1'.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 67  20  TESTE
Error   15  Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' is not defined.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 73  44  TESTE
Error   16  'ReportDefinition' is not a member of 'TESTE.CrystalReport1'.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 75  20  TESTE
Error   17  Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' is not defined.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 81  44  TESTE
Error   18  'ReportDefinition' is not a member of 'TESTE.CrystalReport1'.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 83  20  TESTE
Error   19  Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section' is not defined.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 89  44  TESTE
Error   20  'ReportDefinition' is not a member of 'TESTE.CrystalReport1'.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 91  20  TESTE
Error   21  Type 'CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportOptions' is not defined.    C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 96  48  TESTE
Error   22  Type 'ICachedReport' is not defined.    C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 99  16  TESTE
Error   23  Type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport' is not defined.  C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 107 69  TESTE
Error   24  Type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport' is not defined.  C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 118 74  TESTE
Error   25  Type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport' is not defined.  C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 129 78  TESTE
Error   26  'CachedReportConstants' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 131 20  TESTE
Error   27  Type 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument' is not defined.    C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 138 51  TESTE
Error   28  Type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport' is not defined.  C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 138 116 TESTE
Error   29  'Site' is not a member of 'TESTE.CrystalReport1'.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 140 9   TESTE
Error   30  Type 'RequestContext' is not defined.   C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 144 72  TESTE
Error   31  Type 'CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.ICachedReport' is not defined.  C:\Users\Fernando e Flavia\Fernando\Projetos Programacao\Holerite\TESTE\TESTE\CrystalReport1.vb 144 109 TESTE

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got to solve the problem with the instructinos in link below in SAP Crystal Site:

http://scn.sap.com/community/bi-platform/microsoft-net-sdk/blog/2010/05/04/my-day-1-training-on-cr-2010-beta

Thanks,